# Localization Not Working in Chrome

Tags: c#, google-chrome, localization

We are developing the multilingual application. Somehow we are facing issues with Chrome browser. Here are the language settings that i have made in chrome i have even moved the language to top of the list.
[image]

Here are the settings in the web.config
[image]

When i debug it the current culture is returned as Sweden but the text from sweden resx is not retrieved.

[image]

if i force the uiCulture in the web.config to be "sv-SE" it works. But in the "auto" mode it doesnt work.

Here are the properties of the resx file.
[image]

Please suggest what am i missing here in order to make it work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am posting this as a solution just because it worked for me. I just had to rename my resx file from

> LocalisedText.es-ES.resx to LocalisedText.es.resx

And this worked for me across all the browsers.